# Why am I getting an error for only some form fields?

Tags: php, html, forms

I recently uploaded an html form with its php script to the godaddy server, and after filling out the form fields, I received an error in which there was an "unexpected ';'" at the end of a set of lines.  After some troubleshooting, help from a family member who programs, and scouring the PHP.net web site, I changed the "||"s  to  "&&"s  and the error no longer occurred.  However, I received a different error, and had not made any other changes than the ones I described.  It is this error:

We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

"The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Zip Code you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Email you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Email (in the verify field) you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Phone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Cell Number you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Fax Number you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Time Frame you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Quantity does not appear to be valid.
The Specific Units you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Requested Completion Date you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Billing Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Billing Zip Code you entered does not appear to be valid.

Please go back and fix these errors.

I checked my html for max length in characters, and the other settings for the form fields that appear to be invalid, and none of the settings are broken or misconfigured as far as I can tell.  Here is the HTML and PHP for those lines (do you need any more information?):

[Link to HTML form:](http://www.iscinfosys.com/requestform.html)

PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "presto423@yahoo.com";
$email_subject = "Request Form Data submitted by...";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['fname']) &&
    !isset($_POST['minit']) &&
    !isset($_POST['lname']) &&
    !isset($_POST['cname']) &&
    !isset($_POST['address']) &&
    !isset($_POST['city']) &&
    !isset($_POST['state']) &&
    !isset($_POST['zipcode']) &&
    !isset($_POST['email_from']) &&
    !isset($_POST['vemail']) &&
    !isset($_POST['phone']) &&
    !isset($_POST['cell']) &&
    !isset($_POST['fax']) &&
    !isset($_POST['workbefore']) &&
    !isset($_POST['referral']) &&
    !isset($_POST['services']) &&
    !isset($_POST['timeframe']) &&
    !isset($_POST['budget']) &&
    !isset($_POST['position']) &&
    !isset($_POST['quantity']) &&
    !isset($_POST['units']) &&
    !isset($_POST['specunits']) &&
    !isset($_POST['reqcompdate']) &&
    !isset($_POST['comments']) &&
    !isset($_POST['baddress']) &&
    !isset($_POST['bcity']) &&
    !isset($_POST['bstate']) &&
    !isset($_POST['bzipcode']))

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$minit = $_POST["minit"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$cname = $_POST["cname"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zipcode = $_POST["zipcode"];
$email_from = $_POST["email_from"];
$vemail = $_POST["vemail"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$cell = $_POST["cell"];
$fax = $_POST["fax"];
$workbefore = $_POST["workbefore"];
$referral = $_POST["referral"];
$services = $_POST["services"];
$timeframe = $_POST["timeframe"];
$budget = $_POST["budget"];
$position = $_POST["position"];
$quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
$units = $_POST["units"];
$specunits = $_POST["specunits"];
$reqcompdate = $_POST["reqcompdate"];
$comments = $_POST["comments"];
$baddress = $_POST["baddress"];
$bcity = $_POST["bcity"];
$bstate = $_POST["bstate"];
$bzipcode = $_POST["bzipcode"];

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$fname)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$minit)) {
$error_message .= 'The Middle Initial you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$lname)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$cname)) {
$error_message .= 'The Company Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$address)) {
$error_message .= 'The Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$city)) {
$error_message .= 'The City you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$state)) {
$error_message .= 'The State you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$zipcode)) {
$error_message .= 'The Zip Code you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$vemail)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email (in the verify field) you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$phone)) {
$error_message .= 'The Phone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$cell)) {
$error_message .= 'The Cell Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$fax)) {
$error_message .= 'The Fax Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$workbefore)) {
$error_message .= 'Your entry does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$referral)) {
$error_message .= 'The Referred By you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$timeframe)) {
$error_message .= 'The Time Frame you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$position)) {
$error_message .= 'The Position you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$quantity)) {
$error_message .= 'The Quantity does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$units)) {
$error_message .= 'The Units you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$specunits)) {
$error_message .= 'The Specific Units you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$reqcompdate)) {
$error_message .= 'The Requested Completion Date you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$baddress)) {
$error_message .= 'The Billing Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$bcity)) {
$error_message .= 'The Billing City you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$bstate)) {
$error_message .= 'The Billing State you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$bzipcode)) {
$error_message .= 'The Billing Zip Code you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($fname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Middle Initial: ".clean_string($minit)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Company Name: ".clean_string($cname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";
$email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\n";
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
$email_message .= "Zip Code: ".clean_string($zipcode)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Verify Email: ".clean_string($vemail)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Cell: ".clean_string($cell)."\n";
$email_message .= "Fax: ".clean_string($fax)."\n";
$email_message .= "Have you ever worked with Home Turf before? ".clean_string($workbefore)."\n";
$email_message .= "How did you hear about Home Turf? ".clean_string($referral)."\n";
$email_message .= "Services Being Requested: ".clean_string($services)."\n";
$email_message .= "Time Frame: ".clean_string($timeframe)."\n";
$email_message .= "Budget Range: ".clean_string($budget)."\n";
$email_message .= "Your Position: ".clean_string($position)."\n";
$email_message .= "Quantity: ".clean_string($quantity)."\n";
$email_message .= "Units: ".clean_string($units)."\n";
$email_message .= "other units, please specify: ".clean_string($specunits)."\n";
$email_message .= "Requested Completion Date: ".clean_string($reqcompdate)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
$email_message .= "Billing Address: ".clean_string($baddress)."\n";
$email_message .= "Billing City: ".clean_string($bcity)."\n";
$email_message .= "Billing State: ".clean_string($bstate)."\n";
$email_message .= "Billing Zip Code: ".clean_string($bzipcode)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I spot:

1. You should not have changed the `||` to `&&`.  The `if` condition checks to see if any of those fields is empty, and you caused it to check if *all* of them are empty.
2. Following that, the whole next block should be enclosed in `{}`, OR a block of code is missing. It appears that if any of the fields is empty (`!isset()`), some error condition is executed, and if all of them are filled in, it should proceed to the last long block and validate each.

.

```
// Possibly something like:
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['fname']) ||
    !isset($_POST['minit']) ||
    !isset($_POST['lname']) ||
    ...
    ...
    !isset($_POST['bstate']) ||
    !isset($_POST['bzipcode']))
{
  // Echo an error that all fields must be filled in.
}
else 
{
  // All were filled in, execute the rest and validate
  $fname = $_POST["fname"];
  $minit = $_POST["minit"];
  $lname = $_POST["lname"];
  $cname = $_POST["cname"];
  $address = $_POST["address"];
  $city = $_POST["city"];
  $state = $_POST["state"];
  // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That must be some form! :-)

Seriously, it would probably help you to reduce the size of this code. For a start, why not store those expected variable names in an array:

```
$vars = array('fname', 'minit', ...);
```

which you can then use to a) check they've been sent:

```
foreach ($vars as $var)
{
    if (!isset($var))
    {
        // Do whatever happens if at least one value hasn't been sent
    }
}
```

b) set those local variables:

```
foreach ($vars as $var)
{
    $$var = $_POST[$var];
}
```

(although, this really isn't necessary; why not just refer to `$_POST['fname']`, etc.?)

c) in conjunction with another array, or a more sophisticated initial one, handle the validation, e.g.

```
define('RE_STRING', "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/");

$vars = array
(
    'fname' => array('type' => RE_STRING, 'full' => 'First Name'),
    ...
);

foreach ($vars as $var => $details)
{
    if(!preg_match($details['type'], $_POST[$var])) {
        $error_message .= 'The '.$details['full'].' you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
}
```

d) build the email message:

```
foreach ($vars as $var => $details)
{
    $email_message .= $details['full'].": ".clean_string($_POST[$var])."\n";
}
```

If you combine that all into a single `foreach` loop, you'll save yourself a lot of code and reduce the chance of a tiny typo causing a lot of headaches.